# How to handle token storage in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have an application that uses [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for user authentication. When a user login in the app, the backend returns an `access token` and `refresh token`, my question is:

**both tokens must be stored in the same storage/place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will have to store it in the same storage. I'd suggest using something like [Secure Store](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) or Async Storage to store your JWT tokens. And when your application is launched, retrieve the access token from Secure Store and store it in memory. Redux preferably, so you don't have to constantly retrieve it from Secure Store each time you make an API call. But, avoid storing the Refresh Token in Redux because you will not use it as often as your access token.

Comment: ok, let me understand. the best option is store both tokens in a secure storage, either keychain, sesitive info, or the one you suggest?. other thing is, when the App is launched I should to check refresh or access token? because in my case access token expire every 5 min...

Comment: Yep. The one I suggested uses keychain services on IOS and on Android it stores in Shared Preferences after encrypting the tokens with Android's keystore system. Of all the options we have, Secure Store is the best one. Not the ideal one though. Because there is no ideal one actually. You can implement these without secure store as well, but you will pretty much be doing the same thing as the library does.

Comment: @CristianFlórez  To answer your second question, you should send the access token to the server. The server authenticates the token. If the token's expired, the auth server sends back a 401 error code, which you have to intercept on the frontend with something like Axios interceptors. After receiving the expired error code, you send the refresh token to the server to generate a new pair of tokens, or just the access token (again as per your implementation). Then the new tokens you store again in Secure Store, the access token in Redux.

Comment: What about if I'm not using expo, I'm using 'raw' react-native. Can I use `SecureStore`? can you explain this a little better this "You can implement these without secure store as well, but you will pretty much be doing the same thing as the library does.", then I could use `asyncstorage` and not a secure storage, where I have to create a utility to interact with the `secure storage` and another one to interact with the storage that doesn't save the info in the keychain/Shared Preferences...

Comment: You can use Secure Store without expo as well. https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-secure-store#installation-in-bare-react-native-projects It's quite easy to set up. Ultimately, what you are doing is encrypting the token and then storing it. That's the key difference between Async Storage and Secure Store. Also, the location where it stores. So, you can implement your own encryption in the application and then store it in Async Storage. You will get the same results. I suggest you read the documentation for async storage and secure store to get a better comparison.